# Mac - Allow user to run MAMP

Tags: macos, administrator, root, mamp

Whenever I start or quit MAMP, Mac OS asks me for the root password. Thats annoying. How can I prevent that? I use only 1 account on my OS. I want MAMP to be controlled without asking for the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a port for Apache higher than 1024.

Ports below that need root privileges.

Comment: Try port 8080. It's above 1024 and has somehow been accepted as HTTP-port

Comment: Yes I will try at home, if that is the solution I will go with it. I think MAMP uses 8888 for default. I just use 80 cause it is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix that was created by web developer [Damian Gaweda](http://www.46palermo.com/about/) that may be of use for you.
He made a 'MAMP-No-Password App' (currently version 1.1) you can read about it and download it  [here](http://www.46palermo.com/blog/run-mamp-without-password-easy-way/). It makes use of an AppleScript 'AppDelegate.scpt' and enables you to run the startup scripts for Apache and Mysql using OSX's keychain. Check it out, it's a neat little hack!